# Deploy multiple web services, i.e. multiple wsdl files, in python

Tags: python, web-services, wsdl, spyne

I'm creating web services in python using Spyne based on [this example](http://spyne.io/docs/2.10/manual/02_helloworld.html). However, all my services are combined into one wsdl file locating at `http://localhost:8000/?wsdl`. I'm looking for another way to deploy each web service separately in a single wsdl file, e.g.
`http://localhost:8000/service1/?wsdl` and `http://localhost:8000/service2?wsdl`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spyne has a `WsgiMounter` class for this:

```
from spyne.util.wsgi_wrapper import WsgiMounter

app1 = Application([SomeService], tns=tns,
        in_protocol=Soap11(), out_protocol=Soap11())
app2 = Application([SomeOtherService], tns=tns,
        in_protocol=Soap11(), out_protocol=Soap11())
wsgi_app = WsgiMounter({
    'app1': app1,
    'app2': app2,
})
```

Now you can pass `wsgi_app` to the Wsgi implementation that you're using the same way you'd pass a `WsgiApplication` instance.

Your Wsgi implementation also would definitely have a similar functionality, you can also use that in case e.g. you need to serve something for the root request instead of an empty 404 request.

An up-to-date fully working example can be found at: https://github.com/plq/spyne/blob/master/examples/multiple_protocols/server.py

Please note that you can't use one `Service` class with multiple applications. If you  must do that, you can do it like this:

```
def SomeServiceFactory():
    class SomeService(ServiceBase):
        @rpc(Unicode, _returns=Unicode)
        def echo_string(ctx, string):
            return string
    return SomeService
```

and use the `SomeServiceFactory()` call for every `Application` instance.

e.g.

```
app1 = Application([SomeServiceFactory()], tns=tns,
        in_protocol=Soap11(), out_protocol=Soap11())
app2 = Application([SomeServiceFactory()], tns=tns,
        in_protocol=Soap11(), out_protocol=Soap11())
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong - does this allow multiple namespaces to be used in single Spyne service?

Comment: thanks for the link to the working example! I was looking for that!