# How do I add HTTP endpoints to a spyne WsgiApplication

Tags: python, wsgi, spyne

If I have a spyne application that inherits from `spyne.Application` and am serving that through a `spyne.WsgiApplication` object, how would I add custom HTTP endpoints to the WSGI server such as `/` or `/info`?

The basic structure mirrors the one found on [spyne.io](http://spyne.io)

```
class HelloWorldService(ServiceBase):
    @srpc(Unicode, Integer, _returns=Iterable(Unicode))
    def say_hello(name, times):
        for i in range(times):
            yield 'Hello, %s' % name

application = Application([HelloWorldService], # <--- spyne.Application
    tns='spyne.examples.hello',
    in_protocol=Soap11(validator='lxml'),
    out_protocol=JsonDocument()
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server

    wsgi_app = WsgiApplication(application)    # <--- spyne.WsgiApplication
    server = make_server('0.0.0.0', 8000, wsgi_app)
    server.serve_forever()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20275836/deploy-multiple-web-services-i-e-multiple-wsdl-files-in-python ? or do you need to do something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `spyne` importing `from spyne.util.wsgi_wrapper import WsgiMounter` ([Source](https://github.com/arskom/spyne/blob/master/spyne/util/wsgi_wrapper.py#L31)) will allow you to call the `WsgiMounter` function with a single dictionary parameter. The keys of the dictionary represent an extension of the root endpoint, and the values are the WSGI-compatible application.

For example:

```
def create_web_app(config):
    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route('/about')
    def about():
        return 'About Page'

    return app

wsgi_app = WsgiMounter({
    '': SpyneAppWsgi(app),
    'www': create_web_app(config)
})
```

..will configure one server, where the [spyne application](http://spyne.io/) will be served from the root, and everything from the `create_web_app` `app` will be served from `/www`. (To get to the `/about` page, you would route to `http://localhost:8080/www/about`)

In this example `create_web_app` returns a [`Flask`](http://flask.pocoo.org/) application.